# Navigation items for navigation controller in interface builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, interface-builder

**-** i have a FirstViewController and a SecondViewController, each has its xib

**-** in the MainWindow.xib i have a UINavigationController, which is connected to IBOutlet

**-** in the AppsDelegate i call

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    FirstViewController * fv = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

    [navigationController pushViewController:fv animated:NO];

    [fv release];

    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**4)** the problem is, when i want to manage Navigation item through interface builder... like for the first view i want to add a button to the right and customize the back text and the title

*sure i could do this using code :
(by fv.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ... and fv.title=@"...") but i want to achive this in interface builder*

- in my FirstViewController.xib and SecondViewController.xib i add a Navigation item and add the a right Bar item

**the problem is, it never shows up and the title doesnt alter**

- if i open MainWindow.xib and add a ViewController (FirstViewController) under the NavigationController (so its listed under it = make it the rootViewController for the NavigationController) and also add Navigation item and Bar Buttom item, whoala, the NavigationBar at the top has the left button
- again this would be great... BUT i cannot do the same think for the SecondViewController, because in interface builder, there can be only one rootViewController under the Navigation Controller... and again if i add the Navigation item in SecondViewController.xib it doesnt show up:(

**- so ho can i manage the Navigation items and Bar button items for multiple ViewControllers in interface builder**

(i looked at most tutorial, but they do it inside the code, by .navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem, what i want to avoid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, the best solution i found

is to design the buttons in Interface builder and link them via Outlet, then in code i simply add them

```
fv.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myOutletButton;
```

i didnt find a way to do it just only in interface builder so it gets bind automaticly :(

Answer (score -3):

If u like to do a separate NVC please instaniate it not from main view, do this from different view's separate.